# twitter4j: Search api not giving last 7 days result

Tags: java, twitter4j

I tried this [code](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java) with keywords as

```
facebook.com
fb.me
```

I got results dating back few minutes

What modification is required to get results dating back few days? I know that twitter does exposes some days historical data. As i tried the same with **tweepy** but got results dating back 3 to 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

search api returns limited number of tweet per request X page. you can use sinceId and maxId to get more tweets.

```
query.setMaxId(maxId);
query.setSinceId(sinceId);
```

sinceId must be the tweetId of last tweet that you got in latest request. 
useful link : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines

Comment: I thought queryResult.nextQuery() does the thing that you mentioned??

Comment: Nope, that approach (nextQuery) works in old way called pagination. Refer to the documentation given above by Aniket Dutta.